# making a custom (non-profit) place in google maps and getting the coordinate of it

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was searching the web for the past two days and I wasn't successful in finding what I want.I want to add my own place (for example my home) to the google maps and then get the coordinates of that place in order to place it in my google maps code in my website.

the only way google is showing me to do so is to add a job for my google coordinates account and then add my custom location(and of course I should pay for it).But this is not a job,I just want my place's coordinates to use in my google maps code!

ps:I've even seen people add their own location with full details of their place in the google maps and I'm pretty sure they didn't pay a penny for it(and everyone in the world can see their place!!!)

So here's the question:How can I do this without paying anything?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the google map on web browser and go to the place what you want by zoom and move and at click you would see the coordnates that you may use in google map code.
No need to add you own place.

Comment: nothing happens on click!!!it just clicks the map!Where are the coordinates supposed to show up?